# Kohana 3.3  правила роутинга и пагинация!

Tags: php, маршрутизация, kohana

Я так понимаю из коханы исключили модуль pagination в итоге перейдя на версию 3.3  я написал его для себя. И вроде бы он работает да вот беда роут вида :

```
Route::set('cp.pagination', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/page/<page>)(/<id>)))', array('page' => '[0-9]+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'cp',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

Прекрасно работал на 3.2 но на 3.3 вылетает исключение:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Required route parameter not passed: id
```

Как бы решить эту проблему или можно стоставить более универасальный роутер для пагинации? Не хочеться плодить по 3-4 правила роутинга когда в принцепи можно обходится общим правилом. И где можно почитать об изменениях в роутах на версии 3.3

Ну и следом вопрос 3.3 приняли стандарт PSR-0 имена директорий и файлов далжны быть с заглавной буквы. Как это будет влиять на linux хостингах  будет ли отрабатывать одинакого URL вида Directory/Controller/Action/ и directory/controller/action,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О **маршрутах**. Если погуглить "Required route parameter not passed kohana 3.3", можно наткнуться на страницу [оф. форума](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/11220), где идёт разговор про ошибку из-за, я так понимаю, невложенных необязательных параметров:

```
..(/page/<page>)(/<id>)..
```

[Исправят](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4630) в 3.3.1.

Есть временное [решение](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4630#note-6) - прописать переменную в `defaults` пустой. Вот так:

```
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'cp',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'page' => '', // вот это оно
));
```

Но еще для версии 3.2 авторы [советовали](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tips#dont-try-and-use-one-route-for-everything) использовать столько роутов, сколько надо.

По поводу **стандарта для имен**, в исходниках `Route::matches()` проскакивает `ucwords`, значит всё будет работать. 
Для того, чтобы и вовсе ничего не переделывать (или переделывать постепенно):

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load_lowercase')); // см. bootstrap.php:49
```

Comment: Они конечно замечательно советуют. Но помойму как то это не особо гуманно плодить 2 правила на один что бы отрабатывала и dir/controller/action/page  и dir/controller/action/id/page! Это печально что это баг. У них нет расписания выхода версий?

Comment: Наоборот, хорошо, что баг, иначе не исправляли бы :)  
О расписании ничего не знаю, Но там, кажется, есть [решение](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4630#note-6): прописать эту переменную в defaults как пустую:

    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'cp',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'page' => '', // вот это
    ));

Отпишитесь, если заработает.

Comment: Да если составить роутер вот так: <pre><directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)(/page/<page>))) </pre> то да забивание пустотой page в defaults помогает! Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Прекрасно, обновлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё лучше страницы передавать в $_GET. Это упрощает роутинг и проще для программирования. К тому же, ваш роут - это и есть ЧПУ для массива $_GET.